# How to fit line in 3d space (not plane)

Tags: r, curve-fitting

How do I perform a fit through the most dense regions of the z <- (x,y) presented on the plot attached?

[image]

The thing is that i tried locfit(z~lp(x,y)) but instead of a line in 3d space I received a plane fit.

Comment: What have you tried? Care to provide reproducible example? There are a number of functions that can go about this. Try local polynomial regression fitting implemented in `loess`.

Comment: As I said before I tried: locfit(z~lp(x,y))

Comment: Are you trying to tell my that using locfit it is not possible to find the ortagonal distance regression fit line/curve?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you simply want a nonlinear fitting function for  `z=f(x,y)` or are you asking how to reject points not in the "dense region" before fitting?

Comment: Yes, simply the function. But I want a curved line through the most possibly dense regions. Instead I keep getting a curved plane of best fit.

Comment: I think your confusion is that *any* function `z=f(x,y)` defines a 2D-surface in 3D space.  It looks like what you want is a set of parametric equations `x=f1(t), y=f2(t),z=f3(t)` .

Comment: I think you are right. But will considering 3 separate estimates for x,y and z give the same result as fitting this providing the fitting function with 3d cordinates at once? My guess was no, and that is why I've been trying to find a way to fit that curved line with 3d points instead of splitting this into 3 separate problems. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and point me towards any solution if any exists.